# WebSecurity.Initialized is true but tables don't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My web app has a self-installation process; it detects (correctly) that the database isn't initialized, and initializes it (via migrations); I also have automated integrational tests that test installation works under these circumstances, and smoke-tests logging in and registering the first user (provided on the installation form).

I recently switched from MVC3 to MVC4. I used the built-in storage provider (in MVC3, the `aspnet_*` tables; in MVC4, `WebSecurity` with the `UserProfile` table).

Instead of hand-running all the MVC3 stored procedures from a .SQL file, I now have calls to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`. In fact, my code snippet is:

```
 if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
 {
     WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ApplicationServices", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
     MigrationsWrapper.MigrateToLatestVersion(); // wrapper around migratordotnet                     
 }
```

Unfortunately, I've noticed an interesting "bug." When I compile my server code and run my installation tests, it passes (as expected) after a fresh install (empty database). If I immediately run the tests again, it fails.

The reason for failure? In my installation test, I nuke all the DB tables, and expect installation to recreate them. However, in this case, **`WebSecurity.Initialized` returns true instead of false.** So, I never hit the second line (initialize and create tables). If I move that line outside, I will get an exception that I'm double-initializing.

Unfortunately, what I really need here is a method like `WebSecurity.CreateTables()`, which doesn't exist. I am therefore quite stuck at an impasse. How do I handle this?

Also, if I try recreating the `UserProfile` table myself, I run into an issue with `UserId` (primary key) being inserted as null -- presumably because I'm missing the other tables.

How should I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work-around I have right now is to **reset IIS.** Sad, but true; doing this will reset `WebSecurity.Initialized` and everything works.

Since I need to at app start, I can programatically reset IIS with `Process.Start`.